# How can I ensure this CSS transition animates

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js, transition

I have an image carousel built using knockout & jquery.
To animate the slides I really want to use CSS transitions and NOT jquery animate.
I have this nearly working but I have an issue. 
In the code below, the 'slideRight' part doesn't work, however the else part works fine. What's happening is the transition to margin-left 0 is being skipped, even though the transition class has been added.

```
if (slideRight) {
    $(requestedElement).insertBefore(currentElement);
    slideContainer.css('margin-left', -$(self.carousel).width());
    slideContainer.addClass('transition');
    slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
} else {
    $(requestedElement).insertAfter(currentElement);
    slideContainer.addClass('transition');
    slideContainer.css('margin-left', -$(self.carousel).width());
}
```

I've created a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vnw57nx0/2/

As you'll see in the fiddle, the carousel transitions nicely between slides going right to left.

But if you find this line in the javascript:

```
self.setIndex(self.currentIndex() + 1);
```

and change it to:

```
self.setIndex(self.currentIndex() - 1);
```

the slides should cycle in reverse.
They do, but they're not being animated.
Interestingly, if I debug the script and step through it works fine.
This made me think it was a timing issue and maybe I need to use a callback function but jquery .insertBefore, .css and .addClass are all synchronous.

Any ideas how I can fix this code that works if I debug but doesn't if I don't?

Comment: Have you heard of GreenSock? It has very powerful hardware accelerated animations.

Comment: Yes I used the tweening on another project recently but in this case I don't want to add another library, I want pure CSS transitions. I'll probably refactor this as well so that it doesn't need jquery either.

Comment: A console.log of your counter shows that you go through the slides incrementally. But when you change to -1 it doesn't. I couldn't find a line that said something like "if < 0 slidecounter = 5"...maybe I missed it.

Comment: It has: if (requestedIndex < 0) {
            requestedIndex = self.slides().length - 1;
        } else if (requestedIndex >= self.slides().length) {
            requestedIndex = 0;
        }

Comment: You can debug the fiddle if you're using chrome - add 'debugger;' without the quotes to the javascript where you want it to break and make sure you have chrome dev tools open (F12).

Comment: Have you tried using http://api.jquery.com/promise/ to make your own callbacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the browser doesn't make a transition when you revert a style value within the same context. You need to do it in a new context using something like `setTimeout`:

```
if (slideRight) {
    $(requestedElement).insertBefore(currentElement);
    slideContainer.css('margin-left', -$(self.carousel).width());
    setTimeout(function() {
        slideContainer.addClass('transition');
        slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
    });
} else {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vnw57nx0/3/

I found this question because of the Knockout tag, and although you've got Knockout references in your question, the problem has nothing to do with Knockout. In fact, your code is very anti-Knockout since you're using jQuery selectors within your "view model" and using observables where none are needed or even useful.

Comment: Thanks for this and I appreciate the constructive critism. I'll give your solution a try tonight when I get home from work. Interestingly I've just been looking at another issue I'm having at work with knockout on iOS6 and your name has come up!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Michael it worked perfectly. I've done updated jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/antonosmond/bf10rdnw/

I took note of your other points as well. I'd already refactored it to avoid jquery but the other points you mentioned were valid and I've tidied up the knockout model a little.